# Linked List in C

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

Heres a snippet from the code I am trying to complete for building a linked list. for some reason I keep getting the error "error: expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘struct’ " when trying to compile the code. Can someone help me out.

```
struct node;
struct node* buildList(int x);
void push(struct node** headRef, int data);
int findLen(struct node** headRef);

struct node{
  int data;
  struct node* next;
}

struct node* buildList(int x){
   struct node* head = NULL;
   head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

   head->data = x;
   head->next = NULL;

   return head;
}
```

Comment: just missing a semicolon at the end of you struct, `struct node { ..... };`

Comment: okay so in C you must put semicolon at end of every struct?

Comment: yes pretty much. there are some contrived counter examples.

Comment: If this question is about C, please remove the C++ tag. Also the other way around.

Comment: @dfeuer, the same problem can arise in C or C++. I don't fully understand your complaint.

Comment: @LuisColorado, tagging a question with both C and C++ is strongly discouraged unless the question is specifically about both languages.

Comment: @dfeuer, I have had exactly the same problem with students in both languages with people who forget to put the semicolon in the last structure of a header file.  This is weird and far too common to illustrate on both languages, as the compiler error normally deals you to the next definition (out of the include file) where you don't see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting a semicolon after the struct declaration

```
struct node{
             int data;
             struct node* next;
           };
```